# Limitation of developing Android application with Adobe Flash CS5

Tags: android, flash-cs5

What is the limitation of developing Android application with Adobe Flash CS5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CS5 requires the Air runtime which can only be installed on devices with Android OS 2.2 or higher.